# Ext JS Eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, extjs, plugins

I want to add ext java script(ext j s) plugin in eclipse.i found o the website that its paid.
and how will i add the ext java script(ext j s) plugin in eclipse?
I am even not able to find any proper resource on the web as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..Spket plugin for Eclipse

https://github.com/DIRACGrid/WebAppDIRAC/wiki/How-to-setup-Eclipse-for-developing-ExtJs

I followed the same and got it working in Eclipse.
And yeah..that is a freeware.!!